# Connection android mssql

Tags: java, android

I press the button, and nothing happens, please help me. When you click on the button, the text in the TextView should change, but this does not happen. I added jtds to the libs folder and Project structure did everything.

```
package com.example.db;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class ConnectionHelper {
    Connection con;
    String database, ip, port;

    public Connection ConnectionClass()
    {
        database = "android";
        ip = "192.168.56.1";
        port = "1433";

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;

        try{
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtbs.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc.jdbc:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+";"+"databasename="+database+";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
        }


        return connection;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.db;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Connection connect;
    String ConnectionResult = "";
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void GetTextFromSQL(View v)
    {
        TextView tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx1);

        try{
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
            connect = connectionHelper.ConnectionClass();
            if(connect!=null)
            {
                String query = "Select * from Tabble";
                Statement st = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    tx1.setText(rs.getString(1));
                }
            }
            else{
                ConnectionResult="Check connection";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.db">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DB">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In the run tab:

```
04/30 00:01:35: Launching 'app' on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86.
Install successfully finished in 1 s 191 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.db/com.example.db.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 21688 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/com.example.db: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/com.example.db: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/com.example.db: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/com.example.db: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf21f4ce0, tid 21716
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf21f57d0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf21f57d0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf25381d0) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf21f5530, tid 21716
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fb93f000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=858ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=7931727961529, Vsync=7932511294831, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=7932517765000, AnimationStart=7932517808800, PerformTraversalsStart=7932518757100, DrawStart=7932524318700, SyncQueued=7932526467100, SyncStart=7932527472800, IssueDrawCommandsStart=7932527780500, SwapBuffers=7932535240400, FrameCompleted=7932587097200, DequeueBufferDuration=198900, QueueBufferDuration=9719100, GpuCompleted=-7596402803422855178, 
I/com.example.db: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 37944(2476KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 91% free, 2340KB/26MB, paused 632us total 888.550ms
E/Error: net.sourceforge.jtbs.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: you have an empty catch `catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }` so how do you know there isn't an exception happening ?

Comment: FYI: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)